# How to stop natbib from modifying bibliography style

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

I am editing a conference proceedings volume for Springer. Springer provides a bibliography style file (spbasic.bst), but several authors have used the natbib package in their source in order to be able to use \citet.

However, the use of natbib seems to override the bibliography style. As such these papers end up having a bibliography style that is inconsistent with the rest of the papers in the volume.

Is there a way to make natbib play nicely with spbasic.bst?

Comment: You might need to add a lot more information to this question, like a mwe, not everyone is familiar with springer templates, where to get the templates, often they are not on ctan. What exactly is natbib changing? None of this is listed, so it is rather hard to help

Comment: @daleif Thanks for your input. I'll add all the information shortly including code and outputs.

Comment: Since you are clearly not using `biblatex` (`.bst` styles and `natbib` are incompatible with `biblatex`), I have removed the tag to avoid confusion.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [Author-year citation with natbib and Springer's spbasic bibliography style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/131624/2693)?

Comment: @AlanMunn Although both involve spbasic and natbib, it isn't a duplicate. I am using numbers, so that's not the issue. It will be more evident when I upload a MWE soon.

Comment: @MGA So you are loading `natbib` with the `numbers` option?

Comment: Maybe just remove `natbib`, make `\citet` an alias for `\cite` with `\let\citet\cite` (instead of doing a search-replace, so that you can revert easily in case you change your mind) and fix up anything that looks odd in the resulting output by minor rewriting. (Aah, the joys of editing other peoples' c... err, stuff.)

Comment: I assume, the authors use `\citeauthor`. Is it for [LNCS](https://github.com/latextemplates/LNCS)? Maybe, one can use [biblatex-lncs](https://github.com/neapel/biblatex-lncs/)? I am unsure, however, if LNCS support is complete there.