# Cite keys appear in Reference list: natbib and spbasic in Springer LaTeX template

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing

A LaTeX newbie is trying to use the templates provided by the Springer publishing house for academic articles. The formats are `spbasic.bst` and `spjour3.cls`. All I've added to this is `babel` for a quote in Greek (which compiles). I've built a file in TeXstudio and exported my bibliography from Zotero with the very helpful [Better BibTeX for Zotero][1] addon. Before that, the Reference list (bibliography at the end of the compiled doc) did not appear at all. There are several other minor problems I've been able to figure out, but the BibTeX management is the most difficult.

However now the compiled References (in `author-date` format) has the cite key appearing before the reference item, e.g.:

> [Butterfield (2010)] Butterfield J (2010) Less is Different, etc...

This is not the acceptable format. How to get rid of this?

NB I don't want a numbered bibliography, but the Chicago author/date format. 
I'm not hitched to Zotero/TeXstudio at the hip, so other software that might be advised would be most welcome.

Forum searching has not yielded any results.

This question was later marked as a duplicate, but neophytes like myself may not be convinced by that as my file compiled, but incorrectly. Thus thinking this was a clearly defined problem (the "number" of the reference in brackets being replaced by the citekey), I thought just removing the iteration of the citekey in the bibliography style would fix the problem. I spent about three full days tying to figure out how to change the bst, dtx, and cls files to do so. Forget about it. You have to either dive very deep and learn more than I was able to, or find a different Springer template and go with that. That springer offers this as an author-date option I don't understand. If you get the above result, you simply have a package incompatible with author-date systems. I ended up adapting an Elsevier template and we'll see if it gets accepted. Even that took a lot of work with a lot of illogical things like removing a sentence in the above source files that kept on reappearing though I couldn't find it anywhere, templates looking for and using packages stored deep in the hard drive with different names than those in the package as stated, cleaning caches and having completely different results even though the packages didn't call for them... all the while reading pompous things *everywhere* such as: "you can use any text editor" as if that were the most serious choice you had to make. You're supposed to think it's all in the code. Don't believe it, it's as wooly as a Wyoming bachelor party and I spent last week thinking I was the sheep. Either dive very deep or get a different template. At times it can be fun in the fiddling, but then you still have the manuscript to prepare.

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}

%opening
\title{Holism or Abstraction}
\author{WT}

\date{13 May 2018}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Each revolution in brain science prompts mechanistic explanations of the mind. 
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
Each revolution in brain science prompts what might be called a ‘holistic’ reaction.\footnote{Following Fodor’s \cite{fodor_holism_1992} catch-all aspersion.} hat Husserl called a category error,\footnote{He used the Aristotelian phrase “\textgreek {μετάβασις εἰς ἄλλο γένος}” \cite[55-56]{husserl_logical_2001}}.they engage in a very complex, and turbid, form of scientific representation. 
\section{Computational Representation in Psycholinguistics}
If gestalt has made its greatest contributions in the realm of visual percept.

\section{Conclusion}
Why an idealized mathematical system that gives only an approximation of phenomena gives better results is a longstanding question in the philosophy of mathematics, e.g., \cite{wigner_unreasonable_1960}. 

\bibliographystyle{spbasic}
\bibliography{mweholabsbiblatex2.bib}
\end{document}
```

```
@article{wigner_unreasonable_1960,
  title = {The the {{Natural Sciences}}},
  volume = {13},
  number = {1},
  journal = {Communications Mathematics},
  author = {Wigner, Eugene},
  month = feb,
  year = {1960}
}

@book{traxler_introduction_2011,
  title = {Introduction: {{Understanding Language Science}}},
  isbn = {978-1-4051-9862-2},
  publisher = {{Wiley-Blackwell}},
  author = {Traxler, Matthew J.},
  year = {2011}
}

@book{fodor_holism_1992,
  address = {{Oxford}},
  title = {Holism},
  shorttitle = {Holism},
  publisher = {{Blackwell}},
  author = {Fodor, Jerry A. and LePore, Ernest},
  year = {1992},
}

@book{husserl_logical_2001,
  address = {{London}},
  series = {International },
  title = {Logical Investigations},
  volume = {1},
  publisher = {{Routledge}},
  author = {Husserl},
  year = {2001},
}

@article{wigner_unreasonable_1960-1,
  title = {The },
  volume = {13},
  number = {1},
  journal = {Communication},
  author = {Wigner, Eugene P.},
  month = feb,
  year = {1960},
  pages = {1-14}
}
``'

  [1]: http://retorque.re/zotero-better-bibtex/installation/
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) with code that compiles so that we can help you.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/271223/29873

Comment: What is this **bold face** diatribe about? Either you are preparing a manuscript for submission to a specific journal, then use the provided template and guidelines (and ask the publisher for help, if something doesn't work) or you are just writing a document on you own, then simply don't use those templates....

Comment: Thank you for the assistance from the link you gave, DG', but it wasn't really a "duplicate" situation since my file compiled. Naturally, I presumed the solution was easier to resolve and spent days trying to do so. Let people understand what they're getting into before wasting a great deal of time around a deadline. Regarding "help" submitting a manuscript from a publisher, forget it. Otherwise, why are there so many stax regarding these publishers' templates? The real question is why the templates themselves don't work for the formats the publishers require.

Comment: @WalkerTrimble -- Granted that publishers could do better, but at least some publishers don't use the file an author submits as the actual production version.  Often, it is translated to XML as the archival format, and LaTeX may or may not be used as the final formatter.